App cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer
I am on macOS 14.6 and developed an app with Xcode. The .app file runs fine. However, if I upload it on Google drive and then download it, I get the error message in the screenshot attached. Still, I enrolled as an apple developer, so I don't understand why this is not working.
Do you have any suggestion ?
Thanks


Did you create a Developer ID certificate, and use it to sign and notarize your app? See "Signing your apps for Gatekeeper".

Yes, as you've been told, you merely need to notarize the app. — By the way, you (and others) can still install and run the app even if you don't notarize it. It's just more work.
